# Function or something to identify Widget (set soem ID for widgets) and change widget child

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't find how this can be done. I want to be able from anywhere (any class and widget at any dart file) with OnTap option (or other) to locate any specific widget I need by ID or something and change it's child. For exampel I may have a button at AppBar, InkWell at bottomNavigationBar, InkWell or Lists at many other widgets, but anywhere I tap I need to be able to jsut locate a specific wifget (by ID will eb best) and tell that widget to change it's child to somethign new.

Exactly as ytou can do at Javascript/Jquery - load some Ajax content or anything and then find DIV by it's ID and $('#divid).html(something). Similar way to be created for widgets.

Something like this:

```
Widget(
  widgetID: 5,
  child: Text('Hello'),
)

InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    FunctionToChangeWidgetChild(
       widgetID: 5, 
       child: SizedBox(width: 100, height: 100),
    );
  }
)
```

I don't need to change just text from one text to other, but change child compeltely. From one widget to other (that may have more nested widgets inside of course, inside SizedBox we may have Row with texts and etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GlobalKey`, Which will locate which state coming from the widget is related.

Example:

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      // Add TextFormFields and ElevatedButton here.
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: I guess with GlobalKey() I can't really set ID 1, 2, 3 ... for widgets or custom name IDs like "game1", "playerbox" or etc. I have to use _formKey (actually without _, just formKey, as it will be used in separate files) ... I guess that will be good enough ...